# Can I include PHP in an XSL file?

Tags: php, xslt, recaptcha

I'm trying to add a captcha field into a form within an XSL file but the PHP doesn't appear to be rendering on the page:-

I currently have:-

```
<xsl:call-template name="signature">
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="signature" />
</xsl:call-template>

<?php
require_once('/recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "public_key";
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>

<div class="forum_default_margin_top">
<input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="Submit" onclick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(); if (!f.checkPostTopicValues(document.forms['new_topic'].topic_subject, document.forms['new_topic'].topic_text, document.forms['new_topic'].signature, true)) return false;" class="forum_default_margin_right" />
<input type="reset" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="return f.cancelNewTopic('{forum/uri}', 0)" />
</div>
```

There is more code above and below but the above displays how I have tried to include php in the file but nothing renders at the front end - even I include an echo statement

```
echo "Hello World";
```

This still doesn't display on the front end.

Any help greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: What kind of server is this on?

Answer (score 2):

Your file extension is probably not being parsed by the PHP interpreter.

There are ways to change this and have every XSL file parsed by PHP before it leaves the server. However, this is not really good for reasources, as it would apply to all XSL files.

The simplest and most resource-saving way would be to give the XSL file a `.php` extension and to send the proper MIME type (is it [this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#media-type-registration)? I don't know) along to make sure it gets treated correctly on the client side:

```
header("Content-type: {insert type here}");
```

it's not pretty to have the `.php` extension there like this, but maybe vanity isn't your concern.

Comment: I'm not sure about the parsing but it wasn't breaking the page and causing a ton load of XLSTprocessor errors to appear on the page (like many other attempts I made to add recaptcha) - So, I would like to think that perhaps this was parsing (I don't know?). This directory alone contains 43 XSL files all of which are called into one another and referenced throughout.

Comment: I was pretty certain changing any file names would break something and sure enough - changing the XSL to PHP extension causes: Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [xsltprocessor.importstylesheet]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Comment: @Geoff well, that must have to do with whichever system you're using - you'll need to look at it to find out how to fix this. But as found out in the discussion with Alvaro above, it's probably even more complex than that

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, I don't think I'll even bother attempting to add a captcha, I just can't deter spammers unfortunately - what a ridiculous system! Thanks though Pekka.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that:

- The file has `*.xsl` extension and your web server is not configured to process `*.xsl` files as PHP code.
- PHP code shows up unparsed in the document, but you are using your browser's rendered view to see it, rather than *view source*.

There're several possible solutions but the easiest one is to:

1. Rename the file to `*.php`.
2. Add this on top of the file:

   ```
   <?php header('Content-Type: application/xslt+xml'); ?>
   ```

*P.S. Rather than including PHP in a XSL file, you can include XSL in a PHP file ;-)*

Comment: This is a complex (and somewhat $hit) CMS platform with hundreds of XSL files all interlinking with one another for various modules - The entire XSL file calls in other XSL templates all throughout the document - it also references a classes / functions file and all relays through an XLSTprocessor (it's all way beyond me as I haven't got a clue about XSL and how this processor works) but I'm pretty certain starting to change the file extension of any files will cause pretty much the entire module to break :/

Comment: Yep, that's a different beast. You'll have to inject your dynamic stuff using the framework's mechanism (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Never really had the correct answer, so 4 years later...

Put the include or require within an xsl:text block, disable output escaping and use a CDATA section.

EG:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
        <![CDATA[<?php require_once 'path/to/file.php']]>
</xsl:text>
```

You could also have php within the CDATA section. Obviously the output of the xsl needs to be a php file, and be called as that in the browser or whatever.

Alternatively you can also call php functions from within XSL. Check the doc's here: http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php

Comment: This looks like it could be promising zak, thanks for your input. Alas, I am no longer using this platform on any project so am unable to test it out but hopefully this should help any future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have file called `recaptchalib.php` at the root of you file system? I suspect not...

I think this line:

```
require_once('/recaptchalib.php');
```

...should be...

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
```

If you `require()` a file that does not exist, it will cause a fatal error. Keep in mind that `require()` takes a *local* path, so that leading slash refers to the root of your local file system, not your web server's document root.

Comment: This isn't the issue, the file is located at the root. Thanks

Comment: @GeoffJackson no problem - just seemed like the most likely answer. Álvaro G. Vicario and Pekka have both posted basically the same answers, and that is the next most likely culprit - your XSL file is not being passed to the PHP interpreter. The possible solutions to this are many and varied, but they have both suggested whats probably the easiest, which is to give your file a `.php` extension.